# Android SDK setText confusing char[] element with int

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm still rather new to Java programming, so maybe there is an obvious answer to this but I've searched my code and the web and can't find the root of this problem. I have created this method in a layout file for my application:

```
    public void setNumLabels(char[] labels){
    int niCC = getChildCount();
    for(int c = 0;c < niCC; c++){
        if(getChildAt(c) instanceof TableRow){
            TableRow tr = (TableRow) getChildAt(c);
            int trCC = tr.getChildCount();
            for(int rc = 0;rc < trCC;rc++){
                if(tr.getChildAt(rc) instanceof Button){
                    ((Button) tr.getChildAt(rc)).setText(labels[c*3+rc],1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that the compiler (and apparently `Dalvik`) sees "**labels[c*3+rc]**" in the setText as an int instead of a char. What am I missing? For now, I've read the char[] element into a String and used that for setText but that seems kinda inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the list of `setText` methods on the `Button` class.

There are:

- `setText(int, TextView.BufferType)`
- `setText(int)`
- `setText(CharSequence)`
- `setText(CharSequence, TextView.BufferType)`
- `setText(char[], int, int)`

I do not understand which of these methods you are trying to use.
If I interpret what you want to do correctly, you could replace that call with:

```
((Button) tr.getChildAt(rc)).setText(labels, c*3+rc, 1);
```

Comment: I had missed the "char[],int,int" version of setText. That's the one I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

Instances of `String` are objects. `char[]` is not an object. `char` is not an object. `char[]` has little to do with `String`. `char` has even less to do with `String`.

> For now, I've read the char[] element into a String and used that for setText but that seems kinda inelegant.

I'd delete the `char[]` and do something that makes sense in Java. `char[]` is virtually never used in Java due to all sort of issues (e.g., encoding problems for Unicode). For example, use a `String[]` for arrays of strings.